# How do I get a working example more compliant with the basics of jquery plugins

Tags: jquery-plugins

My first fumbling with jquery plugins wwning myself off DOM object manipulation.
I have read so much about plugins that it is making my brain hurt. Although I have got the plugin to do what is expected. I can't believe the way I've set the variables and initialisation is correct. While not requiring all eventualities to be addressed, I would be grateful if you could comment on the more non-compliant aspects in order that future plugins can be tackled with a degree of confidence. Example  http://www.wordscans.com/jtest/ (ignore outer ring)

The Code..

```
enter code here

<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><HEAD>
<script type=text/javascript src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src='RkJQRotate.js'></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
function kickoff() {makeins(); ringpos();
  setTimeout('$("").rotateinner()',200); $('#ovobj').rotoval();}

function makeins() {
  jQuery('<div></div>',{'id': 'tmplx','lft':'-90','top':0, 'ang':0}).addClass ('incirc').appendTo('body');
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {idrf='incir'+i; var img='pic/rot'+i+'.gif';
    $('#tmplx').clone().attr('id',idrf).css({'background-image':'url("'+img+'")'}).appendTo('body');}
  $('#ovalob').clone().attr('id','ovobj').appendTo('body').fadeIn(40);
   $('#ovobj').css({left:'50px',top:'50px','display':'block'}).fadeIn(40);}

function ringpos() {var coord=$('#ringhold').offset(); VposX=coord.left; VposY=coord.top;
  var inca=360/Velnum; Vstang=Vstang%360; var sang=Vstang; var rad=Vdiam/2; var offs=((Vringw-Vwdh)/2);
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {var erf='#incir'+i; var quadr=Math.floor(sang/90); var cang=sang%90;
    var ang=cang*(Math.PI/180); sang+=inca;/*radians*/
    var x=rad*Math.cos(ang); var y=rad * Math.sin(ang); xx=(quadr%2)?x:y; yy=(quadr%2)?y:x;
    xx=(quadr>1)?-xx:xx; yy=(quadr%3)?yy:-yy; erf='#incir'+i; rlt=VposX+xx+offs; rtp=VposY+yy+offs;
    $(erf).css({left:rlt+'px',top:rtp+'px','display':'block'}).fadeIn(40);}  }

var Vdiam=152; var Velnum=4; Vwdh=98; Vht=98; Velm='ringhold'; Vstang=45; Vringw=300;  Vinc=-2.001; var VposX; var VposY;

(function($) {
  var inca=360/Velnum; inca=(Vinc<0)?-inca:inca;  var rad=Vdiam/2; var offs=((Vringw-Vwdh)/2);
  var trig=1; var trigovl=1; var intval=null; var intvalo=null;
  //rotateinner=function ()
  $.fn.rotateinner=function () {/* return setInterval(function() Dont try chaining* with return*/
   if(trig==0) { clearInterval(intval); return}
   intval=setInterval(function() {var v=Vstang+Vinc; Vstang=(v>360)?v%360:(v<0)?360+v:v; var sang=Vstang;
      for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {var erf='#incir'+i; var quadr=Math.floor(sang/90); var cang=sang%90;
        var ang=cang*(Math.PI/180); v=sang+inca; sang=(v>360)?v%360:(v<0)?360+v:v;; /*radians*/
       var x=rad*Math.cos(ang); var y=rad * Math.sin(ang); xx=(quadr%2)?x:y; yy=(quadr%2)?y:x;
       xx=(quadr>1)?-xx:xx; yy=(quadr%3)?yy:-yy; erf='#incir'+i; rlt=VposX+xx+offs; rtp=VposY+yy+offs; 
       $(erf).css({left:rlt+'px',top:rtp+'px'}); };  }, 85); }
  var lgrad=230; var smrad=120; var stang=45; var oincr=2.2; var low=280;
  $.fn.rotoval=function() { 
    if(trigovl==0) { clearInterval(intvalo); return}
      jqobj='#'+this.attr('id'); 
   intvalo=setInterval(function() {
     if($(jqobj).attr('oang')==undefined) {$(jqobj).attr('oang',stang);}
     oang=$(jqobj).attr('oang'); 
     var quadr=Math.floor((oang)/90); var rnang=(oang%90); rnang=(rnang)?rnang:0.01;
     if(quadr%2){rnang=90-rnang;}  var rnang=rnang*(Math.PI/180);
     var frma=lgrad*smrad; var frmb=Math.pow(smrad*Math.sin(rnang),2);
     var frmc=Math.pow(lgrad*Math.cos(rnang),2)
     var radfac=frma/Math.sqrt(frmb+frmc); 
     var x=radfac*Math.sin(rnang);var y=radfac*Math.cos(rnang); 
     xx=(quadr<2)?x:-x; yy=(quadr%3)?y:-y;
     rlt=VposX/1+xx/1+offs; rtp=VposY/1+yy/1+offs+low; 
     $(jqobj).css({'left':rlt+'px','top':rtp+'px'});
     var v=oang/1+oincr+0.001; oang=(v>360)?v%360:(v<0)?360+v:v;
     $(jqobj).attr('oang',oang);}, 80); }
})(jQuery);

<style>
.incirc {display:none;position:absolute;width:98px;height:98px;z-index:20}
</style>
</head>
<body onload=setTimeout('kickoff()',100);>
        <div id='ringhold'><div id='ringbs'></div><div id='ringtp'></div><div id='ovalob' class='ovalob''></div></div>
</body></HTML>
```

Thanks for any possible help with this AND THANKS to all who who have spent time contibuting to this site as a first stop when priblems arise.

Comment: noone can read that bro =(